# Why is isequaln(f, simplify(f)) false?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a function `f` that is defined as:

```
syms c a t
f = symfun(c + t - (2*(t - 2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t), [c a t])
```

However, checking for equality with the simplified version yields:

```
isequaln(f, simplify(f))

ans =

     0
```

Is `simplify` not expected to return an exact equivalent of the original function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem with `isequaln`**

The [`sym/isequaln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequaln.html) is probably not the appropriate function to use to test the equality. From the help for `sym/isequaln`:

> isequaln(A,B) returns true iff A and B are identical treating NaNs as equal.

As @Benoit_11 alludes to, the documentation is not entirely clear, but, like it's numeric equivalent, the function appears to be testing for [equality, not identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Types_of_equalities) (despite the unfortunate use of the word "identical"). The simplified function is an identity for the unsimplified function, but it is not an equivalence. As per the documentation, `sym/isequaln` may take into account things like [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions.html) and possibly simple relations, but it doesn't perform a transformations and simplifications internally. This is almost certainly because simplification is a computationally costly process, so it was likely a design decision to only include a few well-defined (but not well-documented) tests.

**A possible solution with pitfalls**

So, how can you proceed? In addition to `sym/isequaln`, the Symbolic Math toolbox includes [`isAlways`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) to test equalities and and inequalities a bit more rigorously:

```
syms c a t
f = symfun(c + t - (2*(t - 2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t), [c a t])
g = simplify(f)
isAlways(f==g)
```

However, in R2014b this returns `false` and the following warning:

```
Warning: Cannot prove 'c + t - ((2*t - 2*2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t) == c +
2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2)'. 
> In /Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/toolbox/symbolic/symbolic/symengine.p>symengine at 56
  In sym.isAlways at 38
```

You should be aware that symbolic variables are assumed complex by default and that `isAlways` is trying to prove this relation for *all possible combinations* of complex values of `c`, `a`, and `t`. Simplification is also an ill-defined process – from the documentation for [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html#btrwama-2):

> Simplification of mathematical expression is not a clearly defined subject. There is no universal idea as to which form of an expression is simplest. The form of a mathematical expression that is simplest for one problem might be complicated or even unsuitable for another problem.

If you look closely at your original equation, you'll see that it contains a singularity that has been simplified away. In R2014b, evaluating `g(1,1,2)` returns `3`, but evaluating `f(1,1,2)` returns:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Division by zero. [_power]
  Evaluating: _symans_32_15992

...
```

**Using assumptions**

If you know something about your symbolic variables, you may be able to avoid this by applying assumptions, e.g.

```
syms c a t
f = symfun(c + t - (2*(t - 2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t), [c a t])
g = simplify(f)
assume(t>2*a)
isAlways(f==g)
```

which now returns `true`. By the way, using @Benoit_11's example, `syms a b; isAlways((a+b)^2==a^2+2*a*b+b^2)` also returns `true` directly.

Comment: +1 great answer! Much better than mine and good job in explaining what I couldn't :)

Answer (score 2):

The function simplify returns the simplest algebraic form of the function you provide it. According to Matlab's doc:

> isequaln recursively compares the contents of symbolic data structures
>   and the properties of objects. If all contents in the respective
>   locations are equal, isequaln returns logical 1 (true).

It's obscure to me how Matlab checks the 'content in the respective locations', but it looks like although the simplified function is algebraically equivalent to the original, its 'content' is not at the same location than the original so Matlab sees them as being different.

As @horchler rightfully mentionned in a comment, testing 2 functions' equality with one set of input arguments is hardly a solid proof, like the following, so take this answer with a grain of salt:

```
%//Define f and S = simplify(f);
syms c a t
f = symfun(c + t - (2*(t - 2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t), [c a t])

f(c, a, t) =

c + t - ((2*t - 2*2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2))*(a - t/2))/(2*a - t)

S = simplify(f)

S(c, a, t) =

c + 2^(1/2)*(a*t)^(1/2)

%// Check with dummy arguments:

isequaln(f(1,2,3),S(1,2,3))

ans =

     1 %// seems to work...
```

Out of curiosity if we compare 2 functions, namely (a+b)^2 and a^2 + 2ab + b^2 (which are identical) and check for equivalence:

```
syms a b
x1 = symfun(a^2+2*a*b+b^2,[a b])

x1(a, b) =

a^2 + 2*a*b + b^2

x2 = symfun((a+b)^2,[a b])

x2(a, b) =

(a + b)^2

isequaln(x1,x2)

ans =

     0
```

we get false yet again, although they are equivalent.

Therefore to answer the question 'Why is isequaln(f, simplify(f)) false?' I would say it's because MATLAB organizes their content internally in a different matter so they seem like 2 different functions. I know this is not a great explanation but anyhow I hope that helped.

Comment: Checking equality by evaluating at one point hardly constitutes proof. Also, the overloaded `sym/isequaln` is being used, not `isequaln` – there is no numeric comparison going on. I don't think that this answers the question. Why doesn't `isequaln` return true and/or how can the equality of the two functions be tested?